# ReturnType Next not working for Entry inside another control

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Forms layout like this

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry x:Name="1" ReturnType="Next" />
    <Entry x:Name="2" ReturnType="Next" />
    <Entry x:Name="3" ReturnType="Next" />
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Entry x:Name="4" ReturnType="Next" />
       <Label x:Name="name" />
    </StackLayout>
   <Entry x:Name="5" />
</StackLayout>
```

ReturnType is skipping the 4th one because Entry is inside the other control i.e. StackLayout/Grid and jumping to 4th one. Is there any quick solution for this issue.

Comment: When you use `ItemTemplate`, you could try to find the all the controls in the page and get the Entry according to the Entry type.

Answer (score 0):

Write a command that does it.

`<Entry x:Name="E3" ReturnType="Next" ReturnCommand="{Binding Focus4Command}" />`

In code behind:

```cs
public partial class MyView : ...
{
    public MyView()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         // Needed, so Focus4Command is found.
         BindingContext = this;
    }

    // public property.
    public Command Focus4Command { get; } = new Command(Focus4);

    public void Focus4()
    {
        this.E4.Focus();
    }
}
```

NOTE: Give x:Names that can be referenced easily in code behind. Start with some letter. E.g. `E3`, `E4`.

Comment: The issue is I create these controls dynamically via ItemTemplate so its not kind of hardcoded that I can access with names as there is no name given

Comment: That entire xaml is one ItemTemplate? Please add more XAML to question, to make it clear.